# инстаграмбот ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="name",password="password")

bot.follow("lorrian123")
```

Ошибка:

```
File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 443, in login
    if self.api.login(**args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 240, in login
    self.load_uuid_and_cookie(load_cookie=use_cookie, load_uuid=use_uuid)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 199, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    return load_uuid_and_cookie(self, load_uuid=load_uuid, load_cookie=load_cookie)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_login.py", line 352, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    cookie_username = self.cookie_dict["ds_user"]
KeyError: 'ds_user'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Я попытался что бы он подписался на человека

Comment: Библиотеки по работе с инстаграмом делают с помощью реверса их поддерживать сложнее, а это значит скорее всего (это не точно, так как здесь источник библиотеки не прикреплён) автор конкретной библиотеки его забросил. Судя по ошибке не получилось подхватить нужный cookie файл, так что попробуйте на гитхабе/гитлабе/pypi отыскать другой репозиторий, который поддерживают и обновляют в наше время. Не будете же вы руками реверсить приложение и чинить код)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй с **instapy**. Тут ты сможешь добавить сразу несколько id, и бот будет на них подписываться

```css
from instapy import InstaPy
session = InstaPy(username="логин", password="пароль")
session.login()

id = ["ID ЮЗЕРА"]
session.follow_by_list(followlist=id, times=1, sleep_delay=600, interact=False)
```